# Why do I get this error on first load of website?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 191

Backtrace:

File: /home/im/public_html/index.php
Line: 321
Function: require_once
```

I get this error on first load of the page. What will be the solution?

My Config session as below.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOVRN.png)

Comment: ... what error?

Comment: Likely a path issue.

Comment: Re edit your question by clicking on edit button and show your session config settings on application/config/config.php

Comment: The above error appears when I load my site for the first time.and IF i reload again it disappears.

Comment: Please check the question..Edited and added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

> Change this `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');` to
>   your auto load config file in config folder

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: My Auoload config is 
$autoload['libraries'] = array("database", 'session', 'form_validation', 'encryption');

Comment: Please check the question..Edited and added the screenshot

Answer (score -1):

> You are getting this Error because you might have windows server. for
>   that i have a solution just follow bellow steps.

1) Go to your `system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php`.

2) Open `Session_files_driver.php` file with `sublime` or your `Code Editor`.

3)  Now Find `function open($save_path, $name)` Function Or `throw new Exception`.

4) Now Just `remove` or `comment` else part method as bellow.

```
public function open($save_path, $name)
    {
        if ( ! is_dir($save_path))
        {
            if ( ! mkdir($save_path, 0700, TRUE))
            {
                throw new Exception("Session: Configured save path '".$this->_config['save_path']."' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created.");
            }
        }
        elseif ( ! is_writable($save_path))
        {
           // This line you have to comment and save file.
           //throw new Exception("Session: Configured save path '".$this->_config['save_path']."' is not writable by the PHP process.");
        }

        $this->_config['save_path'] = $save_path;
        $this->_file_path = $this->_config['save_path'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            .$name // we'll use the session cookie name as a prefix to avoid collisions
            .($this->_config['match_ip'] ? md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) : '');

        return $this->_success;
    }
```

5) Now save your file and Reload with hard refresh by `Ctrl + Shift + R`.

6) That's it. your file will be run.

Comment: Have  you initialize Session on your `Config.php` file?

Comment: Plz check my sessions configs in question above. I have added it.